# How to distinguish a missing key from a key with value nil in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

We are often testing hash-maps for the presence of a certain key, say `:data`, by testing a trial retrieval of that key's value against `nil`, as in

```
(defn test-my-hash-map [my-hash-map]
  (if (:data my-hash-map) 42 "plugh!"))
```

This produces `42` for any hash-map that contains the key `:data` with any value, *except* the value `nil`.

```
(map test-my-hash-map
     [{:data "Hello!"}    ; ~~> 42
      {:no-data "Yikes!"} ; ~~> "plugh!"
      {:data nil}         ; ~~> "plugh!", but I need it to say 42 :(
     ])
```

I don't see any way to do it at all, and this is messing up some data processing scenarios where we're getting data from non-Clojure sources in which a missing key means "I have no data at that key" and a key with a `nil` value means "I have data there, but I can't give it to you for whatever reason." I don't see a way to distinguish these cases in Clojure code.
My extremely yucchy work-around is to insert a Java shim that detects the differences and inserts extra columns (keys) for the special cases before handing off to Clojure.

Comment: Um, what's wrong with ``(contains? my-hash-map :data)``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a clojure function `get` that allows a default value to be supplied.

```
(:foo {:bar 1}) ; ==> nil
(get {:bar 1} :foo "no key inserted") ; ==> "no key inserted"
```

Of course there's also `contains?`.

```
(contains? {:bar 1} :bar) ; ==> true
```

Comment: `contains` is nice because the code reads  `(if (contains? row :data) ...)`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test for the existence of a key, you can use `contains?`:

```
(contains? {:a nil} :a) ; => true
(contains? {:a nil} :b) ; => false
```

In your case you can provide a default with `get`:

```
(get {:a 42} :a "foo!") ; => 42
(get {:a nil} :a "foo!") ; => nil
(get {:a 42} :b "foo!") ; => "foo!"
```